# How to send string variable as parameter to onload function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm trying to convert files to Base64 and store the string into independent variables:

```
  sellersPermitString: string;
  DriversLicenseString: string;
  InteriorPicString: string;
  ExteriorPicString: string;
```

This is the method I'm using, which only allows me to save the base64 into  `imageSrc`

```
imageSrc;
handleInputChange(files) {
    var file = files;
    var pattern = /image-*/;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    if (!file.type.match(pattern)) {
      alert('invalid format');
      return;
    }
    reader.onloadend = this._handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
  _handleReaderLoaded(e) {
    let reader = e.target;
    var base64result = reader.result.substr(reader.result.indexOf(',') + 1);
    this.imageSrc = base64result;
    console.log(this.imageSrc)
  }
```

This is how I'm trying to save the value of the base64 into my variables, but I'm not getting the first file only the others.

```
 public picked(event, field) {
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if (fileList.length > 0) {
      const file: File = fileList[0];
      if (field == 1) {
        this.sellersPermitFile = file;
        this.handleInputChange(file); //turn into base64
        this.sellersPermitString = this.imageSrc;
        console.log(this.sellersPermitString)
      }
      else if (field == 2) {
        this.DriversLicenseFile = file;
        this.handleInputChange(file); //turn into base64
        this.DriversLicenseString = this.imageSrc;
        console.log(this.DriversLicenseString)
      }
      else if (field == 3) {
        this.InteriorPicFile = file;
        this.handleInputChange(file); //turn into base64
        this.InteriorPicString = this.imageSrc;
        console.log(this.InteriorPicString)
      }
      else if (field == 4) {
        this.ExteriorPicFile = file;
        this.handleInputChange(file); //turn into base64
        this.ExteriorPicString = this.imageSrc;
        console.log(this.ExteriorPicString)
      }
    }
    else {
      alert("No file selected");
    }
  }
```

Any ideas?

In other words I would like to have a method that receives a file and a variable to store the result base64.

[Stackblitz example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vonpxf)

Comment: can you create stackblitz example ?

Comment: Yes give me few minutes

Comment: @MuhammedAlbarmawi there you go, I hope you get the idea https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vonpxf

Comment: convert the image to base64 is async opperation  that why the first file is undefined and the second file will have the first file base64 code , I will write my answer in few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the image to base64 is async operation that why the file is undefined because this line

```
this.sellersPermitString = this.imageSrc;
```

excute before the convert the image to `base64` the problem second time

```
    this.DriversLicenseString = this.imageSrc;
```

`DriversLicenseString`  will containe the value of first file.

the safe it place to set the value is `_handleReaderLoaded`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {


  imageSrc;
  sellersPermitFile: any;
  DriversLicenseFile: any;
  InteriorPicFile: any;
  ExteriorPicFile: any;
  //base64s
  sellersPermitString: string;
  DriversLicenseString: string;
  InteriorPicString: string;
  ExteriorPicString: string;
  //json
  finalJson = {};

  currentId: number = 0;

  addPictures() {
    this.finalJson = {
      "sellersPermitFile": this.ExteriorPicString,
      "DriversLicenseFile": this.DriversLicenseString,
      "InteriorPicFile": this.InteriorPicString,
      "ExteriorPicFile": this.ExteriorPicString
    }
  }
  public picked(event, field) {
    this.currentId = field;
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if (fileList.length > 0) {
      const file: File = fileList[0];
      if (field == 1) {
        this.sellersPermitFile = file;
        this.handleInputChange(file); //turn into base64
      }
      else if (field == 2) {
        this.DriversLicenseFile = file;
        this.handleInputChange(file); //turn into base64
      }
      else if (field == 3) {
        this.InteriorPicFile = file;
        this.handleInputChange(file); //turn into base64
      }
      else if (field == 4) {
        this.ExteriorPicFile = file;
        this.handleInputChange(file); //turn into base64

      }
    }
    else {
      alert("No file selected");
    }
  }


  handleInputChange(files) {
    var file = files;
    var pattern = /image-*/;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    if (!file.type.match(pattern)) {
      alert('invalid format');
      return;
    }
    reader.onloadend = this._handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
  _handleReaderLoaded(e) {
    let reader = e.target;
    var base64result = reader.result.substr(reader.result.indexOf(',') + 1);
    //this.imageSrc = base64result;
    let id = this.currentId;
    switch (id) {
      case 1:
        this.sellersPermitString = base64result;
        break;
      case 2:
        this.DriversLicenseString = base64result;
        break;
      case 3:
        this.InteriorPicString = base64result;
        break;
      case 4:
        this.ExteriorPicString = base64result;
        break
    }

    this.log();
  }

  log() { 
    // for debug
    console.log('1', this.sellersPermitString);
    console.log('2', this.DriversLicenseString);
    console.log('3', this.InteriorPicString);
    console.log('4', this.ExteriorPicString);
  }

}
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-image-base64)